# Regex pattern in C# start with String [ and end with ]

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
test text x=String[%sasdasd%] and b= String[%jj%]
```

Of course I want those regexp for C#.

I want with regexp to be able to get those String[%sasdasd%] and String[%jj%]

That means I want to get all texts that start with String[ and end with ]

What is the best regexp out there?

Answer (score 2):

Match all `String` (literally) followed by open square bracket `\[` followed by any character `.` one or more times `+`, be [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) about it `?` and end with closing square bracket `\]`

```
String\[.+?\]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String\[.*\]
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/ufhLVB/2) for explanation.